# set one image above another android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to create a layout like this:

[image]

I have 3 different images: the background, the white square and the V sign.

How can I position them as in the photo, when I want the box to move from side to side

when onClick is triggered.

I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/off_background">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/handle" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/upper_layer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/switch_v" />

</FrameLayout>
```

which gives me the order correctly, but not posed correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/off_background">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/checkButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/handle"
        android:src="@drawable/switch_v"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can I do this with RelativeLayout?

Comment: Of course you can. Just change FrameLayout texts with RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/off_background" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bottom_layer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/handle" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/upper_layer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/switch_v" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide `android:layout_gravity="center"` for ImageView in your xml

Answer (score 0):

You should really be looking at the [TobbleButton](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html).

Your layout should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/off_background">
    <ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_bg"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

And use a selector (toggle_bg) for the background like below

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

This is of course assuming you have the drawables for the different states of the ToggleButton.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, but I have to use fading in\out animation to the v switch and also the bg color transit from color1 to color2